# How to add widget in a List<ImageProvider>

Tags: flutter

Hello I have a list of image that I pass to a page builder

```
final List<ImageProvider> _imageProviders = [

    Image.asset(
      "assets/page1.png",
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ).image,

Image.asset(
      "assets/page2.png",
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ).image,
...

]
```

---

```
PageView.builder(
      physics: _pagingEnabled ? const PageScrollPhysics() : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: widget.imageProviders.length,
      controller: _pageController,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final image = widget.imageProviders[index];
        return EasyImageView(
          imageProvider: image,
          onScaleChanged: (scale) {
            setState(() {
              // Disable paging when image is zoomed-in
              _pagingEnabled = scale <= 1.0;
            });
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

But I search to add a widget with dynamic text and icon in my first page like that.

```
 final List<ImageProvider> _imageProviders = [

   MyWidget(),

    Image.asset(
      "assets/page1.png",
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ).image,

...

]
```

Answer (score -1):

then change the generic type of list
from :

```
List<ImageProvider>
```

to this:

```
final List<Widget>
```

this will make the items of the list able to be any flutter widget